# LinkedIn Api get Posts/Shares from owner error

Tags: linkedin-api, posts, owner, urn

I want to get shares by owners from LinkedIn api. I used the following url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:{accountId}
```

But I become this error:

> {
>       "serviceErrorCode": 100,
>       "message": "Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/owners]",
>       "status": 403 }

what is wrong? Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: take care that the id of a person is an alphanumeric value, something similar to `yrZCpj2Z12 `  the the call should be like `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:yrZCpj2Z12`

Comment: I use the Id that i become when i call https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id) isn't this right?

Comment: yes, it works for me. Verify your app/token use `r_member_social` for member shares

Comment: thank you i will test it an write a comment again. :)

Answer (score 3):

In this endpoint, make sure you doing request without `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` in your request headers.

Also urn must be escaped.

May be useful for someone, because I had this issue and banged head until i got help from live support.